# How to capture duration between start and end timeStamps that are in UTC in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, utc

I captured around 10K start and end time stamps **using regular expression** variables in JMeter, but they are in **UTC format** as follows `'2016-06-24T18:25:03.621Z'`. I need to calculate the duration time between those time stamps.

I appreciate if someone can provide me a clue on this?

Comment: You can use a beanshell sampler and use java DateFormat to parse the strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert [ISO 8601 dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (like you provided) to i.e. milliseconds since start of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) using [Beanshell Test Elements](http://How%20to%20Use%20BeanShell:%20JMeter's%20Favorite%20Built-in%20Component) and the code like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

vars.put("old_date", "2016-06-24T18:25:03.621Z");

Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(vars.get("old_date"));

Date new_date = cal.getTime();
long new_date_ms = new_date.getTime();

log.info("Date in milliseconds: " + new_date_ms);
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell Demo]

Performing arithmetic operations on [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) values is fairly easy, something like:

```
long date1 = //code to convert ISO 8601 date to long as above
long date2 = //the same for date2

long delta = date2 - date1; //calculate the difference
vars.put("delta", String.valueOf("delta")); // store the result into a JMeter Variable
```